# How avoid/minimize the permission to run the app script that are bound to google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have google-sheet which is utilizing the app-script to do somethings within the sheet itself, (i.e. it is not doing any operation on the google-drive folders). But when I share the sheet with someone else (lets call that person **client**) then, when that person attempts to run the script, there is prompt which asks to grant app-script the access to the his/her google drive. Even though the script is not performing any operations on the client's google drive.

Is there some way in which the client doesn't see the "Provide access to your google drive" - prompt? I am not even doing anything on the google drive.

Answer (score 0):

#### No there is no way to suppress the message

The reason for this is because Apps Script, every time you run one function, even if the function were a simple `console.log("")`, the *whole script* is compiled and checked. This is why you can run this function from the script editor with not problems.

```js
const globalVar = "Hello"

function test(){
    console.log(globalVar)
}
```

It is for this reason, that *all* potential OAuth scopes must be approved before using any part of the script, it is for security as much as anything.

You can set explicit scopes if you want, but if you don't want any OAuth scope authorization, then you will need to remove all references to Drive methods from the script.

#### Reference

[Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes)